# Regular Expression to parse Common Name from Distinguished Name

Tags: regex, macos, bash, distinguishedname, dscl

I am attempting to parse (with `sed`) just `First Last` from the following DN(s) returned by the `DSCL` command in OSX terminal **bash** environment...

`CN=First Last,OU=PCS,OU=guests,DC=domain,DC=edu`

I have tried multiple regexs from this site and others with questions very close to what I wanted...  mainly [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97113/regular-expression-to-parse-ldap-dn)... I have tried following the advice to the best of my ability (I don't necessarily consider myself a newbie...but definitely a newbie to regex..)

`DSCL` returns a list of DNs, and I would like to only have `First Last` printed to a text file.  I have attempted using `sed`, but I can't seem to get the correct function.  I am open to other commands to parse the output.  Every line begins with `CN=` and then there is a comma between `Last` and `OU=`.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/^CN=\([^,]*\).*/\1/' input_file
```

> ```
> ^           matches start of line 
> CN=         literal string match
> \([^,]*\)   everything until a comma
> .*          rest
> ```

Comment: This worked perfectly for when DSCL returned multiple lines.  DSCL is rather inconsistent it seems, as it sometimes returns a single line with all the users in a group.  Thank you!

Comment: a CN can contain comma's which have to be escaped, this regex doesn't work on such names.

Answer (score 7):

I think all of the regular expression answers provided so far are buggy, insofar as they do not properly handle quoted ',' characters in the common name. For example, consider a distinguishedName like:

```
CN=Doe\, John,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local
```

Better to use a real library able to parse the components of a distinguishedName. If you're looking for something quick on the command line, try piping your DN to a command like this:

```
    echo "CN=Doe\, John,CN=Users,DC=activedir,DC=local" | python -c 'import ldap; import sys; print ldap.dn.explode_dn(sys.stdin.read().strip(), notypes=1)[0]'
```

(depends on having the python-ldap library installed). You could cook up something similar with PHP's built-in ldap_explode_dn() function.

Answer (score 2):

Two `cut` commands is probably the simplest (although not necessarily the best):

```
DSCL | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d= -f2
```

First, split the output from `DSCL` on commas and print the first field ("CN=First Last"); then split that on equal signs and print the second field.

Comment: +1 because this is by far the easiest way for someone who doesn't grok regex—the OP should immediately understand how it works.

Comment: I used a combination of these cut commands and `sed` when the output was a single line.  I sincerely appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators

```
awk -v RS=',' -v FS='=' '$1=="CN"{print $2}' foo.txt
```

Comment: Does `awk` allow to specify escape sequences?, as the comma can appear escaped in the Common Name.

Answer (score 0):

I like awk too, so I print the substring from the fourth char:

`DSCL | awk '{FS=","}; {print substr($1,4)}' > filterednames.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This regex will parse a distinguished name, giving `name` and `val` a capture groups for each match.

When DN strings contain commas, they are meant to be quoted - this regex correctly handles both quoted and unquotes strings, and also handles escaped quotes in quoted strings:

`(?:^|,\s?)(?:(?<name>[A-Z]+)=(?<val>"(?:[^"]|"")+"|[^,]+))+`

Here is is nicely formatted:

```
(?:^|,\s?)
(?:
    (?<name>[A-Z]+)=
    (?<val>"(?:[^"]|"")+"|[^,]+)
)+
```

Here's a link so you can see it in action:
https://regex101.com/r/zfZX3f/2

If you want a regex to get *only* the CN, then this adapted version will do it:

`(?:^|,\s?)(?:CN=(?<val>"(?:[^"]|"")+"|[^,]+))`